# Custom Cat6 Ethernet 802.3af not working as it should

Tags: networking, router, ethernet, cat6, ubiquiti

I have a custom cat 6 ethernet that I made with the following 250ft of [Cat 6 from Monoprice](https://www.monoprice.com/product?p_id=13676). Wired with T568B

I have this cable currently, which is roughly 20 feet, going to a [keystone jack](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B06ZXYP9C5) on a patch panel, which is a female / female connector.

On the other side of the keystone, I have a short [Startech Cat 6 patch cable](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B06Y4N379F). Which goes to my Ubiquiti 8 port POE switch.

When I wire up the following, the port only lights up orange (half-duplex?) and powers the AP, but will not provide networking.

AP -> Custom Cable -> Keystone Jack -> Startech Cable -> Switch

When I wire up the following, it DOES work…

AP -> Startech Cable -> Keystone Jack -> Custom Cable -> Switch

I have literally no idea why this would not work in the way I want it to. I verified the Startech cables are wired with T568B and everything matches when I check the cable order and colors. I’ve tried 5 different ethernet cables using the custom cable behind the keystone, but NOTHING works. When I directly plug in the AP to the switch, it also does work. The only situation that I want it to work in, it does not. I truly am puzzled.

Edit: -- Turned out to be the keystone f/f jack and/or the pass-thru connector.

Comment: Have you actually tested the cable? That’s the first thing to do. It’s the most likely problem. Everything else was factory made. You didn’t get something punched down properly or crimped properly, etc.

Comment: I’ll have to grab a tester, I don’t have one unfortunately. I thought it was fine considering if I go AP -> Custom Cable -> Switch it works fine or the second example above too. Just weird in the one scenario it doesn’t, no?

Comment: There’s a number of ways the cable wiring could have gone wrong. So, no, I don’t think it is weird. Hard to explain, yes. Once you figure it out post an answer for us. It’ll be interesting to know what combination of wiring issue caused this. If you continue to have trouble update the question with the new info you have. I’m sure you’re going to find an unconnected wire, shorted wires, or cross connect wire, or maybe a combination. Remember that usually the connection between an AP and Switch would use a crossover cable. But because of Auto-MDI/X it’s not needed. So this adds to the behavior.

Comment: I appreciate you getting back!

I took some time tinkering around with it last night again and it ended up being the rear of the keystone jack. For some reason, the combination of my Cat6 connector (https://www.amazon.com/dp/B07MJ6SWFS) and the rear of the keystone female jack (https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B06ZXYP9C5/) is loose. The moment I apply pressure in a different angle, all the pins seem to make contact and it works as expected. However, any other factory cable works fine on the back. Perhaps the pass through connector itself or the pins are a different size or something?

Comment: Or I could have crimped too hard perhaps? Pushed the pins in too far